# How to convert UIElement (Canvas) content (children) to BitmapImage on Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I'm writing an app for Windows Phone 8.1 in VS 2013.
I'd like to use a WriteableBitmap, which is supposed to be in the System.Windows.Media.Imaging namespace.
But it's not.
I have no System.Windows.Media namespace.
I can't add a reference. I have two references added by the WP8 app wizard: ".Net for Windows store apps" and "Windows Phone 8.1".

Am I missing something?

Comment: the reference must be .NET for Windows Phone and not for the Store!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap
```

You are trying to reference `OLD SILVERLIGHT API's` in `NEW XAML API's`, by using `Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging` you will be able to get the WriteableBitmap class in Windows Phone 8.1 & to know more this [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/%20library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx) will help you.

Hope this is what you were looking for. See if this helps.